# Find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2n+1}}{1+(1+2n)^2},\ \ \ \text{where}\ \ \ |z|\leqslant1 $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find the sum:
> $$
> S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2n+1}}{1+(1+2n)^2},\ \ \ \text{where}\ \ \ |z|\leqslant1
> $$

I tried to factorize the denominator, but it didn't help at all. Could someone give me a clue to the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at $S$ and its first few derivatives

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4n^2+4n+2}\:z^{2n+1}$$

$$S' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{4n^2+4n+2}\:z^{2n}$$

$$S'' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n^2+2n}{4n^2+4n+2}\:z^{2n-1}$$

notice that

$$z^2S'' + zS' + S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{2n+1} = \frac{z^3}{1-z^2}$$

Using the ansatz $S = z^r$ we can get the homogeneous solution:

$$r^2 + 1 = 0 \implies S_h = C_1 \sin(\log z) + C_2 \cos(\log z)$$

The Wronskian of the two functions is $-\frac{1}{z}$. However proceeding further with variation of parameters only yields complex hypergeometrics. It seems likely that $C_1 = C_2 = 0$ and the solution will probably be only the particular part.

Comment: I think the fact $S$ is continuous at $z=0$ gives $C_1=C_2=0$.

Comment: @aschepler well I wanted to make the conclusion but it depends on what form the particular solution takes. $C_1$ and $C_2$ will have to be constants that cancel out the singularity in the particular.